# C - recursively finding subset sum without loops

Tags: c, recursion, subset

I'm looking to get some help. I have this code in c which works to find if there is a subset of an array `set[]` of the size `n` which adds up to `sum`.

Example:

```
 set[] = {1,2,3};
 n = 2;
 sum = 4;
```

The code above would return true because the sized-2 subset `{1,3} = 4`
it will also be true with:

```
n = 3;
sum = 6;
```

but false for:

```
n = 1; 
sum = 4;
```

It works for some cases but the case in the driver doesn't return properly for the driver in this code. Please note that I can't change the parameters and *don't want to use any kind of loops*

and the code is here:

```
#include <stdio.h>

bool isSubsetSum(int set[], int n, int sum)
{
    // Base Cases
    if (sum == 0)
        return true;
    if (n == 0 && sum != 0)
        return false;

    if (set[n-1] > sum)
        return isSubsetSum(set, n-1, sum);

    return isSubsetSum(set, n-1, sum) || isSubsetSum(set, n-1, sum-set[n-1]);
}

// Driver program to test above function
int main()
{
    int set[] = {6,5,6};
    int sum = 12;
    int n = 2;
    if (isSubsetSum(set, n, sum) == true)
        printf("Found a subset with given sum");
    else
        printf("No subset with given sum");
    return 0;
}
```

JAVA adaptation: (Errors too) n is the size for a subset

```
 public static boolean isSubsetSum(int[] set, int n, int sum) {
    int[] copy = new int[set.length - 1];
    System.arraycopy(set, 0, copy, 0, set.length - 1);

    // Base Cases
      if (sum == 0 && n == 0)
        return true;
      if (set.length == 0)       // fixed base case. 
        return false;

      if (set[set.length - 1] > sum) {
        return isSubsetSum(copy, n, sum);
      }

      return isSubsetSum(copy, n, sum) || isSubsetSum(copy, n-1, sum - set[set.length-1]);
}
```

Comment: Can you be more explicit about the fail case of the driver ?

Comment: Any loop can be programmed with recursion (as long as you have a deep enough stack, or tail-call-optimization).  Thank you lambda calculus.

Comment: @Michelle And you'd be wrong. Everything that can be done using loops can also be done using recursion. Moreover, subset sum requires an additional DS to calculate in addition to the loop. (matrix if using DP, or a stack of imitating recursion in brute force)

Comment: possible duplicate of [find all subsets that sum to x - using an initial code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18624567/find-all-subsets-that-sum-to-x-using-an-initial-code)

Comment: Do you assume that your number are positive ?

Comment: @amit Is this true restricted to the given function signature?

Comment: Are you sure about the line `int n = 2;` you don't want `int n = 3;` ?

Comment: You would be better off with `n = sizeof(set)/sizeof(set[0]);` so you always get the number of elements in the set.

Comment: "a subset of an array `set[]` of the size `n`" is ambiguous. Is the set of size `n`, or the subset?

Comment: @hivert n is the size of the subset that must be found

Comment: @hivert and numbers are not assumed to be positive

Comment: @pat it's the size of a subset that must be found

Comment: @Coconop The failure is that it equates to false, when it is true

Comment: AFAIK, C doesn't have `bool` type

Comment: It doesn't have a type that is exclusively Boolean, but there is `stdbool.h` which provides a type named `bool`.

Comment: May the return value be something other than true/false?

Comment: BTW: If numbers may be negative, then code needs to throw out `if (set[n-1] > sum)`.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing the size of the set and the size of the subset. Let `n` design the size of the full set and `k` the size of the subset. Then:

```
#include <stdio.h>
bool isSubsetSum(int set[], int n, int k, int sum)
{
  // Base Cases
  if (sum == 0 && k == 0)
    return true;
  if (n == 0)       // fixed base case. 
    return false;

  if (set[n-1] > sum)
    return isSubsetSum(set, n-1, k, sum);

  return isSubsetSum(set, n-1, k, sum) || isSubsetSum(set, n-1, k-1, sum-set[n-1]);
}

int main()
{
  int set[] = {6,5,6};
  int sum = 12;
  int n = 3;
  int k = 2;
  if (isSubsetSum(set, n, k, sum))
    printf("Found a subset with given sum\n");
  else
    printf("No subset with given sum\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I read the question as meaning `n` is the size of the subset, not the original set. (Especially based on the examples.)

Comment: Thanks for the non bug report. True ! If fixed the base case.

Comment: Still incorrect. Not a big problem, but for a border case. :)

Comment: Still a non bug report !

Comment: @Michelle is correct that n is the size of the subset.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without changing the parameters? Because I have another method that calls this one and the way it's set up, the parameters on this one can't be changed.

Comment: There is no way to find the size of the array in C from inside `isSubsetSum`. So you have to pass it one way or another (eg: using c++ vectors).

Comment: If I were to try my code in Java, would this code work with say set.length? (I'm using C for practice but can easily switch between the languages for the project)

Comment: @user3362954: I think so. But you wont be able to index the set in java the way you are doing with an array.

Comment: @hivert edited my response with java code (and still errors) is this what you were trying to say?

Answer (score 0):

You also need to pass the size of the set as argument. The following code works.

```
#include <stdio.h>

bool isSubsetSum(int set[], int m,int n, int sum)
{

 if (n == 0 && sum == 0)
 return true;
 if(m==0)
    return false;

if (set[m-1] > sum)
 return isSubsetSum(set, m-1,n, sum);

return isSubsetSum(set, m-1,n, sum) || isSubsetSum(set, m-1,n-1, sum-set[m-1]);
}

// Driver program to test above function
int main()
{
 int set[] = {6,5,6};
 int sum = 13;
 int n = 2;
 if (isSubsetSum(set, 3,n, sum) == true)
 printf("Found a subset with given sum");
else
 printf("No subset with given sum");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Anyway of doing it without changing the parameters?

Comment: isSubsetSum won't have any idea of size of set, if it is not passed from calling function. So you have to modify the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `0` at the end of the list to indicate set length.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool isSubsetSum(int set[], int n, int sum) {
  if (n == 0)
    return sum == 0;
  if (set[0] == 0)  // End of the line
    return false;
  if (isSubsetSum(set + 1, n, sum)) // Do not use first element
    return true;
  if (isSubsetSum(set + 1, n - 1, sum - set[0])) // Use first element
    return true;
  return false;
}

// Driver program to test above function
int main() {
  int set[] = { 6, 5, 6, 0 };
  int sum = 12;
  int n = 2;
  if (isSubsetSum(set, n, sum) == true)
    printf("Found a subset with given sum");
  else
    printf("No subset with given sum");
  return 0;
}
```

This works with negative numbers too.